# Pull information from one shapefile and add it to the attribute table of another?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-joins

I'm trying to create a shapefile for one particular area in Germany. I have various shapefiles which store all the information that I need.  One of them is a 100m_Gitter_raster (a raster consisting of hectares) which is going to be the main shapefile that I want to work with. However, the individual raster points are missing information that I need. This is where the other Shapefiles come in handy. Those files cover bigger areas than the 100m_Gitter_raster and I now want to transfer the postal code to the 100m_Gitter_raster layer.

To help visualize my problem here is what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Imagine the green area is the postal code area whereas the little squares in between are part of the 100m_gitter_raster which I want to transfer the data to.

How can I have the 100m_gitter_raster pull that information from the postal code file and embed it into its own attribute table?

I have tried the Reference extension with the geomwithin function, however, this would just crash QGIS.

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`? If so, how does the tool not suite your needs?

Comment: no I haven't. I just tried it and it worked!! Thanks for pointing in the right direction. I didn't no this functionality existed, since I'm rather new to QGIS. Thanks heaps !!